# How to ask someone if we can be on a first name basis?

Tags: word-choice

How to ask someone if we can be on a first name basis?

1. Can we be on a first-name basis?
2. Can we go by a first-name basis?

Are these acceptable?

Comment: Sounds a bit "precious" to me. Just ask *"Do you mind if I call you John, Mr Smith?"* Or more obliquely, make the offer *yourself* - *"Hi, I'm Asdasd Jones - but please call me Azzie"*.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a problem that you might imagine, but rarely actually occurs.

In any casual situation, first names are always used.

In nearly all internal business situations first names are always used.

The only time that last names would be used is when you are speaking to a customer of the business. In this context you can use "Mr" or "Ms" + last name.  If the customer prefers you to call them by first name, they can tell you. You don't need to ask.

But please don't overthink this. Don't ask, just go with what "feels" right.  99% of native speakers won't care too much and most of the remainder would politely tell you as you are a non-native speaker, and we don't expect you to always get this right.

If you really have to ask, then "Can I call you John?" is simple and polite (if you don't know the person's first name, you probably shouldn't ask to use it!)

Here is a comic sketch about this topic ["Can I call you Ted?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V8sFfQo6SA). You should see that the interviewer should just have used "Edward" or "Ted", rather than wasting time asking about names.

Comment: I feel like this is a bit regional and cultural. In modern US, most relationships encourage the use of the first name, even when there is a power or authority dynamic to the relationship, like addressing an employer by their first name. In UK, it seems more common to use last names even for casual or peer relationships, except for the most intimate friends. (In Harry Potter, how many people call him "Potter"? Most of the teachers, and most of the other students aside from Hermione, Ron, etc.)

Comment: Also @ASDASDASDASD I always feel like a good approach is, rather than *asking* for a familiarity that might not be welcome, to start with the most polite forms and stick with them until the other person invites me to do otherwise. Most people will, and on the other hand they may feel it would be impolite to refuse your request even if they're uncomfortable with it.

Comment: I think the Harry Potter scenario is mirroring the British grammar or public school system. No-one in my school was ever addressed by their first name; it was last name or nickname. Even brothers & same names were Smith D/Smith M. The nearby comprehensive, however, where several of my friends went, it was all first names.

Comment: The "schoolboy" use is different.  Firstly don't suppose that Harry Potter is typical.  In 99% of Schools, Teachers use first names to speak to children, and Children use "Mr." or "Sir".  There is a slang use of last names in which children call each other by last name *without Mr or Ms* as a show of familiarity.  Adults don't often do this, and Learners would never need to consider this.